# How can i restrict to delete only one document at a time in firestore using security Rule?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angular6, firebase-security

I have a collection called 'customers' and i have allowed read and write permissions to that collection to some users.My requirement is i have to restrict the delete operation only to one document at a time,to avoid mass deletion of the collection.How can i achieve this using firestore security rule.?Right now i have tried with the below code

```
match /customers/{customer=**} {

    function isSignedIn() {
      return request.auth != null;
    }  

    function isRole(roles) {
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Teachers/$(request.auth.uid)).data.permissions.pages.hasAny(roles);
        }

    function isSize(size){
      return request.resource.data.size()==size;
    }

    allow read: if isSignedIn()&&isRole(['create','modify']);
    allow create,update:if isSignedIn()&&isRole(['create','modify']);;
    allow delete:if isSignedIn()&&isSize(1)

 }
```

Here is the code to delete operation;

```
async(id:string){

  const batch=afs.firestore.batch();
  const coll=await afs.firestore.collection('customers').ref.limit(1).where('id','==',id).get();
  for(const i of coll.docs){
   const ref= await afs.firestore.collection('customers').doc(i.id);
   await batch.delete(ref);
  }
  return await batch.commit();

}
```

but the above rule always returning permission denied while making a delete operation.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show an example of the "mass delete" operation that you're trying to prevent?

Comment: The scenario of mass deletion comparatively very low,but here i have to prevent an accidental bulk deletion;

Comment: Again, what is the specific query you're trying to prevent?

Comment: Note that `batch.dalete(i.ref);` is not a valid API call. It really helps if the code you share is the code you're actually trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible.  Firebase security rules doesn't provide any way to limit the rate or volume of any operation.  There is also no way to detect if the current operation is a part of a batch or transaction.

Even if there was a way to detect if there is a batch operation, the user could still call `delete()` repeatedly to achieve the same effect.

Instead, you could experiment with sending client requests through Cloud Functions, which could try to record requests to delete documents, and reject the request if it exceeds some limit you define.  The documents would have to be fully unwritable by security rules, while they would still be accessible to the Admin or server SDK you use in Cloud Functions.

Comment: How about limiting the query using limit operator in security rule.?

Comment: That limit is refers to the number of documents read in a query.  It has nothing to do with the rate at which documents are accessed.  You won't be able to implement any rate control like that.

Comment: I edited the question to suggest that you could use Cloud Functions to implement your own rate controls.  You would have to write a bunch of code for this.  What you're trying to do can't be done with security rules alone.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable information @Doug Stevenson